# Back Button Not working Properly in Lightning for Visualforce Pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce

On lightning page I have a Button call "Cancel" when I click on it.
It will redirect to "ABC" list view which is working fine in classic but in lightning it's not working properly it's redirecting to "recently viewed" list view.

I have return following custom method for the same.
Controller Method:

```
public static PageReference listView(Schema.sObjectType destinationSObject) {
       Schema.DescribeSObjectResult destination = destinationSObject.getDescribe();
       PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + destination.getKeyPrefix() );
       pageRef.setRedirect(true);
       return pageRef;
    }

    public PageReference doCancel() {
       return listView(Object__c.sObjectType);
    }
```

Visualforce tag:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!doCancel}" styleClass="slds-button slds-button_brand"/>
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Are you using a StandardController in your page? Have you tried StandardController.cancel? This should ideally take you back to wherever you came from. Right now, you're not really going "back", you're going forward to somewhere else that you may not have been before.

Comment: Yes I am using StandardController in page and I have tried standard Cancel action but it's giving this error "The page no longer exists. Try reloading it. If the problem persists, contact Salesforce support."

Comment: And it's working fine in classic but giving error in lightning.